# "get the answer right" what's the part of speech of 'right' here?

Tags: parts-of-speech, idioms-in-context

> Eventually, nearly everyone in the class gets the answer **right**, and the concepts stick with them because they had to find their own way to the answer.

"gets the answer right" what's the part of speech of 'right' here?

Answer (score 2):

That is an adjective. It is a complement in the clause, completing the clause headed by "gets" and describing the answers that they get.

It's not an adverb. It doesn't function to modify the verb or the clause.

Comment: Hey @James K, I’m not so sure one couldn’t see it as an adverb. One could read it as parallel to “answers the question correctly.” And to me, the *right* in OP’s example feels as if it’s performing a different function from the one in “gets the right answer.”

Comment: And compare to, “Nearly everyone in the class heard the teacher right.”

Comment: @Marios Athanasiou, I’m not saying that James K is flat wrong, I’m saying that his is not the only analysis. Consider that [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/right) lists senses of *right* which they label as adverbial, that one of those is, “in a suitable, proper, or desired manner,” and that their example for that sense is “knew he wasn't doing it right.”  “Do it right” and “get it right” seem completely parallel to me.

Comment: At the end of the day, understanding is more important than parsing.  Billions of people understand English, without formally parsing anything. Indeed, it is unknown if the brain mechanisms for converting sounds into meanings map in any way onto the grammarians rules.

Comment: In *do it right*, *right* is an adverb; it is like *do it correctly*. In *make it right*, *make* is an adjective; it is like *make it correct*. We cannot analyse *get it right* simply by parallel structures. It makes more sense to me for *right* to be an adjective because it refers to the answer not the process. There are many examples where people obtain the correct answer by an incorrect process, and they are still said to have *got the answer right*.

Comment: @PaulTanenbaum Hi! It's not easy to understand what part of speech is the word 'right' in a sentence. In the sentence 'Do it right' the word 'right' is an adverb. In the sentence 'Get it right' the word 'right' is an adjective.Those sentences can easily cause you to make a mistake and say that in the sentence 'Get it right' the word 'right' is an adverb.Someone who doesn't know that the word 'right' is an adjective in the sentence 'Get it right' thinks wrongly that the word 'right' is an adverb. Dictionaries help us to understand what part of speech is a word in a sentence.

Comment: @Peter’s analysis resonates for me. Although for me *right* doesn’t 100% obviously apply more to *answer* than to *get*, still I can’t see an exchange like this, Q:”How did you get the answer?” A:*”Right.” But in the end, @James K is right—I guess we’ve danced long enough on the head of this pin.

Answer (score 1):

> **Eventually, nearly everyone in the class gets the answer right, and the concepts stick with them because they had to find their own way to the answer.**

In that  sentence the word **right** is an adjective.

The following example is from Cambridge Dictionary [1](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/right):

> **You got three answers right and two wrong.**

In that sentence the word **right** is an adjective.